# How to store static field?

Tags: spring, static

In a redis java client,I found this:

```
To use it, init a pool:

JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");
You can store the pool somewhere statically, it is thread-safe.
```

I just wondering,with spring,how can I store JedisPool statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

In spring it's preferable to define a JedisPool bean and autowire it wherever necessary.

For example, using xml config:

```
 <bean id="jedisPool" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
      <constructor-arg>
           <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig" />
      </consrtuctor-arg>
      <constructor-arg value="localhost" />
 </bean>
```

and then, inside your beans:

```
@Autowire
JedisPool jedisPool;
```

It's even simpler if you use [spring java config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) - you can use exactly the code you posted to define the pool bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public JedisPool createJedisPool() { 
        return new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");
    }
}
```

Also you might want to take a look at [spring-data - redis](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/redis)